# Maintain tab order even after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Here is the scenario, where I need to maintain the tab order in the page even after a post back.

I have a user control with 3 text boxes, this is placed in a aspx page with other controls. In the onBlur of the test boxes i am doing a __doPostBack to pass some data to server and handle this on the parent page, Because of this the tab order is lost. Is it possible to maintain the tab order in post back, where I tab from the parent page to the text boxes in the control and tab out again to the next parent page control.

I tried setting the focus to the next textbox in the usercontrol using below code, but this causes the code to be called, even when user focus out of the control just by clicking on the page.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            WebControl wcICausedPostBack = (WebControl)GetControlThatCausedPostBack(sender as UserControl);
            if (wcICausedPostBack != null)
            {
                int indx = wcICausedPostBack.TabIndex;
                Panel selectedPanel = null;
                if (Panel1.Visible)
                {
                    selectedPanel = Panel1;
                }
                else if (Panel2.Visible)
                {
                    selectedPanel = Panel2;
                }
                if (selectedPanel != null)
                {

                    var ctrl = from control in selectedPanel.Controls.OfType<WebControl>()
                               where control.TabIndex == (indx + 1)
                               select control;
                    if (ctrl.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        ctrl.First().Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected Control GetControlThatCausedPostBack(UserControl page)
    {
        Control control = null;
        string ctrlname = string.Empty;
        UserAction updateAction = CurrentUserAction();
        if (updateAction != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(updateAction.Data))
            {
                string[] splitSting = updateAction.Data.Split('$');
                ctrlname = splitSting[splitSting.Count() - 1];
            }
        }
        if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
        {
            control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button || c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return control;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to store the currently focused field id in a hidden control.

Storing it in a hidden control would maintain it across postbacks.
You can use that input id to find the next input and set focus to it again using jQuery.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    $("#currectFocusField").val($(this).attr("id"));
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastFocusedInput = $("#currectFocusField").val();
});
```

Comment: code you provided, this will be called always, but i need to set focus only when tabbing from a textbox.

Comment: No, it will not always be called. It will be called when you tabout(focus on the next) input and on ready(after a postback)